# android: EditText numberDecimal - how to start the keyboard as minimized

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have an EditText with these values:

```
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

As you see, I would like to insert only digits 0-9.

my problem is that when I reach the layout containing this EditText, the smartphone keyboard is displayed so it hides the screen before I can see the screen content. (although I didn't press on the edit text box!)

I would like the keyboard to be minimized as default.

I want that **ONLY AFTER I press on the editText box**, the keyboard will be displayed.

Is there any possibility to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EditText` is gaining focus on activity load. To prevent this you can do as following:

**METHOD 1:** Add below attribute to your parent layout

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

**METHOD 2:** In manifest add the following attribute to your activity inside activity tag:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the  [InputMethodManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html), calling *hideSoftInputFromWindow*, passing in the token of the window containing your focused view

```
// Check if no view has focus:
 View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
 if (view != null) {  
 InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0); 
 }
```

This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some cases you will want to pass in **InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY** as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down menu).